# Fixing VTK 6.2 linking errors

Tags: c++, vtk

Using VTK 6.2, there are multiple link errors when trying to make a project:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkWrappingTools
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkGUISupportQt
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkWrappingPythonCore
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkFiltersPython
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkGUISupportQtSQL
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkRenderingQt
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkglew
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkGUISupportQtOpenGL
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkLocalExample
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkViewsQt
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkoggtheora
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkGUISupportQtWebkit
```

## Problem:

Unresolved linker errors. This may be a path issue, since the libraries appear to be present in `/usr/local/` but are not seen by `ld` at compile time...

## Background information:

- OS is Ubuntu 13.10
- VTK is 6.2 from the Kitware github
- CMake file follows guidelines supplied by the [Kitware CMake for VTK 6+ docs](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Build_System_Migration)

VTK was configured as an out-of-source CMake build (no problems) followed by make and make install so that all of the libraries are correctly placed in `/usr/local/lib`.

My project build now uses the following CMakeLists.txt:

```
# Add VTK, insist that it uses 6.2, 
find_package(VTK 6.2 EXACT REQUIRED NO_MODULE)
include(${VTK_USE_FILE})

find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)

set_property(DIRECTORY APPEND PROPERTY COMPILE_DEFINITIONS ${VTK_DEFINITIONS})

include_directories(
  ${VTK_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIR} 
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
)

####################
# Make my_target
####################

set(EXE my_target)

set(SOURCES 
  my_target.cpp
)
add_executable(${EXE} ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(${EXE} ${VTK_LIBRARIES} ${GLEW_LIBRARY} )

###################
```

Answer (score 4):

Change the find_package parameters to specify just the modules that you want. For example:

```
find_package(VTK 6.2 EXACT REQUIRED COMPONENTS 
    vtkRenderingOpenGL vtkInteractionStyle NO_MODULE)
```

This 'fix' took some time to find. It looks like the default behaviour is for CMake to include **all** VTK modules ... some of which may not exist. If you specify components then the default behaviour is disabled. Unfortunately, it can be quite difficult to know *what* libraries to include, and so it would be nice to have the default "include everything" behaviour working!

My simple program didn't use Python or Qt, but `ld` still wants to resolve those basic libraries. This appears to be normal behaviour even when VTK is built without the Qt or Python modules.

This may be a bug in VTK 6.2. I'll raise it with Kitware, and revise the answer as/when new info is available...